# Mobile login form using jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, xampp, dreamweaver

I want to make a mobile application on android and I use adobe dreamwever cs6, php and mysql(bundle on XAMPP). I have a problem on my login process.
Can you tell me where is the errors of my code? because my login form only stuck on loader when i press the login button. Please help me.

This is my index.html code on dreamweaver...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css"/>
  <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btnLogin").click(function() {
        username=$("#username").val();
        password=$("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"login.php",
            data:"username="+username+"&password="+password,
            success: function(data){
                    if(data=='true'){
                            window.location ( "hhome.html");                                
                        } else {
                                $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/icons-png/alert-black.png' />Wrong Username or Password!!");
                            }
                },beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' />")
                    }
        });
        return false;
});
});
</script>
</head> 
  <body> 

    <div id="page" data-role="page" >
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
      <div align="center" data-role="content" data-theme="a" >  
         <img src="sma-baktiidhata.jpg" width="214" height="178"><br>
           <p>Go to the login page</p><br><br>
           <a href="#page2" data-role="button">Login</a>     
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" >
           <h4></h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
         <h1>Login User</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <form action="login.php" method="post" id="add_err">
           <div data-role="fieldcontain">    
           <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />        
           <input name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value="" maxlength="10" />
           </div>
           <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="btnLogin" value="Login" />        
        </form>
     </div>
     <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
         <h5>&copy; 2014 </h5>
     </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try changing $(document).ready(function() { to $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page", function(){

Comment: take out ( $(document).ready(function() {) create a separate js file for all for your functions and link at the end of the HTML page after the html tag. Its not good practice to have scripts inside the page.